LSI 9266-8i will not load BIOS Configuration Utility
I have an LSI 9266-8I card that will not enter BIOS configuration.
This is a replacement, intended to be used in place of a prior card of the same model.  When I boot the system with disks detached, I get a message saying,
All of the disks from your previous configuration are gone,  If this is
an unexpected message, then please power off your system and check your
cables to ensure all disks are present.

This message is actually a surprise since the card was advertised as New from Amazon, but I pressed C - I do want to configure the card.
Entering the configuration utility in this state will result in drive
configuration changes.  press 'Y' to continue loading the configuration uility
or please power off your system and check your cables to ensure all disks are
present and reboot.

Here, I press Y.
After a few seconds, the system presents the Ubuntu boot menu (GRUB) and never offers the BIOS configuration utility.  I contacted the seller on Amazon, and got a replacement card, which exhibits the same exact scenario.
I have also booted, and have run the following command:
MegaCli -AdpFacDefSet -a0

after which I was prompted to reboot.  Once I did, the same scenario occurs.
What might I do in order to enter that utility?


Not press C, but Ctrl-C. 2. Video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ggdbgjm8cRQ might help... or not.

